On team, in team, or from team?
Which of the following is better?
a) "You have a new message from Shelly from the Pepsi vendor team:"
b) "You have a new message from Shelly on the Pepsi vendor team:"
c) "You have a new message from Shelly in the Pepsi vendor team:"
I originally had option a) but then realised that the word "from" was repeated.

There's nothing wrong with repeating a preposition. "on the team" vs "in the team" might be a regional thing, so where are you from?

We use US English

I'd use 'at' or 'of' here.

In accord with (half of) Edwin Ashworth's answer, I think that 'of' is the most natural-sounding option. In effect, the sentence at issue is a shortened form of "You have a new message from Shelly, who is a member of the Pepsi vendor team." Ultimately and unavoidably, however, I think that this question calls for opinion-based answers because I don't see how anyone can make an absolute, objectively defensible case for the superiority of one preposition over all others.

All three prepositions are in use...

...and I can't see any reason to suppose they aren't all completely interchangeable in any given context. Prepositions are often flexible in English. Asking which is "better" is pointless. If you don't already have a preference for some reason, just use on because it's the most common, not because it's objectively "better" in some way.
